# How can I submit this form properly with javascript/greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, greasemonkey, hidden

How can I submit this form properly with javascript/greasemonkey?

```
<form action="/user/cart/add/66004574/93973071" method="POST">
<button class="text" value="upvote" type="submit">
<i class="icon-plus"></i>
Add to Cart
</button>
<input type="hidden" value="1337250c-b697-4e0e-b8fa-56bdedc8cd6a" name="_csrf_token">
</form>
```

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could submit this form like this:

In this function you can process the data of the form.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     // get the data of the form
     var url = $(this).attr("action"),
         _csrf_token = $(this).find("input name=['_csrf_token']).val();

     // jquery ajax call for example
     $.ajax(

     );
});
```

Comment: Thx but that didn't work to submit the form, nothing happens.

Comment: You have to finish the $.ajax call, else nothing will happen. try do add `alert("Form submitted");` after `e.preventDefault();`